# Imposibilidad de actualizar una app en Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Tenemos una app que hemos modificado innumerable cantidad de veces, vamos por la versión 45 en producción, y siempre nos acusa un error de la versión 22 que fue en el canal de pruebas abiertas.
Dicho canal ya está inactivo. Esto sucede por más que al publicarla coloco no incluir versiones anteriores. La misma app si la publico con otro nombre (ApplicationID), se publica correctamente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, No se entiende la pregunta, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Solucionado: Al quedar una versión activa con error en un canal de prueba (aunque el canal esté inactivo), las nuevas versiones (aunque sea en otro canal, en este caso de producción) la siguen incluyendo. Lo solucioné publicando la nueva versión correcta de producción en el canal de prueba, colocando que no incluya las versiones anteriores. Al publicarse correctamente la versión en el canal de prueba, automáticamente se publicó correctamente en el canal de Producción.
Muchas Gracias a gbianchi y Jorgesys por su colaboración.